# Why I need the inline keyword when I am not defining any method twice?

Tags: c++

I am practicing inheritance and Abstraction in C++. I have a base class which is named Animal and a derived class named Dog. I am having trouble when I am trying to separate the definition from the implementation for my base class.
The base class, Animal has an interface (.h file) and an implementation(.cpp file).

The following is the code from Animal.h -

```
class Animal {

    const char * _name;
    int _numberInPack;
    int _numberOfLegs;

    Animal() {};

public:
    Animal(const char *, const int, const int);
    const char * nameOftheAnimal();
    int numberOfLegs();
    int numberInPack();
};
```

and the Animal.cpp is as follows -

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Animal.h"

Animal::Animal(const char *name, const int numberInPack, const int numberOfLegs) {
    _name = name;
    _numberInPack = numberInPack;
    _numberOfLegs = numberInPack;
}

const char * Animal::nameOftheAnimal() {
    return _name;
}
int Animal::numberOfLegs() {
    return _numberOfLegs;
}
int Animal::numberInPack() {
    return _numberInPack;
}
```

If, I do so, I get the following error.

```
LNK1169 one or more multiply defined symbols found.
```

What is going on here?

The error looks like this -

[image]

If I just add the keyword `inline`, I don't get the error anymore. Like-

```
public:
    inline Animal(const char *, const int, const int);
    inline const char * nameOftheAnimal();
    inline int numberOfLegs();
    inline int numberInPack();
```

What is this `inline` keyword doing?

Any help would be really appreciated.

My main.cpp is following-

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Animal.cpp"


int main()
{
    Animal an("Tommy", 5, 4);
    printf("The animal has %d legs\n", an.numberOfLegs() );


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you `#include "Animal.cpp"` in your `main.cpp`.  That means that the function definitions will be included in the object files for both `main.cpp` and `Animal.cpp`.

The proper way to go about this is to `#include "Animal.h"` (instead of `"Animal.cpp"`) in `main.cpp`, and then tell your linker to include the object files created from both `main.cpp` and `Animal.cpp`.

---

The reason that adding `inline` to your declarations seemed to work is that the compiler will inline the functions rather than generating object code to be sorted out by the linker.  The problem with this approach is that now you *have to* include the definitions of said functions in every source file they are used.

---

Some of your functions are good candidates for inlining, since they are short.  E.g. `nameOftheAnimal()`, `numberOfLegs()` and `numberInPack()`.

If you want to inline them, the function definitions could be added to  `"Animal.h"` (and removed from `"Animal.cpp"`).

Comment: Along with proper way, address the real question "Why does adding inline work here?"